# Proving product group isomorphic to group of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I’m studying for my exam in algebra and I’m trying to show that
$$(\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z})^*$$
Is isomorphic to the product of two groups $A$ and $B$ with 2 and 6 elements respectively. I was thinking since
$$\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z} $$
Then maybe
$$(\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z})^* \cong  (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^* \times (\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^* $$
It appears to be true in this case, but I would like to show the above statement in general, if it’s true, but I haven’t been able to show that there is a homomorphism between the two

Comment: For any two rings $R,S$, we have $(R\times S)^{\ast}=R^{\ast}\times S^{\ast}$. Furthermore, an isomorphism of rings $T\cong R\times S$ induces an isomorphism $T^{\ast}\cong(R\times S)^{\ast}$. Putting these two facts together yields what you want. Which of the two (or perhaps both) is the one not clear to you?

Comment: Start from this: a pair $(u,v)$ is invertible (in the ring product) if and only if both $u$ and $v$ are invertible (in their corresponding rings).

Comment: @Thorgott I was not familiar with any of these results, but I suppose the second one follows more or less directly from how inverses behave under a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.